# AngularJS class type check solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jsdoc

### In short

How can I do type check on constructors and functions of a user-defined class, typically in AngularJS's dependency injection environment?

### Background

I have a legacy angularjs code with heavy data objects. Code files are filled with so many (about 50) simple angularjs factories like:

```
    .factory('ContainerTypeModel', function () {
        var ContainerTypeModel = function (name, constantCode) {
            this.name = name || "";
            this.constantCode = constantCode || "";
        };
        return ContainerTypeModel;
    })

    .factory('ContainerTypeFactory', ['ContainerTypeModel', function (ContainerTypeModel) {
        var ContainerTypeFactory = {
            newByModel: function (/** ContainerTypeModel */model) {
                return new ContainerTypeModel(
                    model.name,
                    model.constantCode
                );
            }
        };
        return ContainerTypeFactory;
    }])
```

Sadly, I may need to change the the property of the models(like `ContainerTypeModel`) a lot due to business reasons. And that is definitely causing the constructor and factory function calls mismatch the parameters. So I

### My surveys

### typescript:

may need to rewrite all the legacy code=.=

### Facebook flow:

may not working due to dependency injection.

### JSDoc:

(I'm currently working in WebStorm 10) still figuring out how to do object type checking, like checking the parameter in `ContainerTypeFactory.newByModel(model)`.

Comment: In the previous month, I migrated my frontend model classes to typescript. The result was that I nearly used the interfaces I designed in other places besides my models, probably because all the code is working just fine (for now) and the schedule is tight. So I could not utilize type check in the whole project, which makes the migration barely useful.
Finally I removed all the specific property definition in my models. If there's no real type check, why exist at all. Moreover, I can respond quickly to model changes after doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> may need to rewrite all the legacy code=.=

Consider the transform from :

```
.factory('ContainerTypeModel', function () {
    var ContainerTypeModel = function (name, constantCode) {
        this.name = name || "";
        this.constantCode = constantCode || "";
    };
    return ContainerTypeModel;
})
```

to :

```
class ContainerTypeModel {
    name: string;
    constantCode: string;
    constructor (name, constantCode) {
        this.name = name || "";
        this.constantCode = constantCode || "";
    };
}
 // later
.service('ContainerTypeModel', ContainerTypeModel)
```

The good news is that *you can do this progressively*. And when you do make the shift it will start highlighting mistakes ... so the transformation will be mostly *guided by the compiler*.

## More

Checkout [why typescript](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html) and [migrating from JavaScript to TypeScript](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces to describe your business model, and a factory to create your domain objects

Something like:

```
interface IContainerTypeModel {
  name : string;
  constantCode: string;
}

interface IContainerTypeFactory {
  (name:string, constantCode:string) : IContainerTypeModel; 
}

angular.factory('ContainerTypeFactory', function():IContainerTypeFactory {
    var containerTypeFactory : IContainerTypeFactory = function (name, constantCode) {
        return {
           name : name,
           constantCode : constantCode
        }
    };
    return containerTypeFactory;
});
```